# Set targetSdkVersion = 22 still need in app permission for Marshmallow device?

Tags: android, permissions, camera, android-camera, android-manifest

I used the camera in my app, since it is not necessary to use the 6.0 API and I would like to skip the in app permission setting, I have set the target SDK to 22.

The manifest is like this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

The problem is , for those 6.0 device , I still need to enable the permission in the setting page, otherwise, the camera is not able to connect.

How to fix it? thanks

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, check the `targetSdkVersion` in the `build.gradle` file. That file overrides the manifest settings.

Comment: yes, change at gradle works , thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Gimme a minute, and I'll find the duplicate I usually use for this so we can close out your question. Cheers!

Comment: @user782104 marked as duplicate .Don't take me wrongly